How can I dynamically update a data validation list in Excel based on unique values from a filtered table?
I'm working with a large dataset in Excel and need to create a dynamic data validation list that only shows unique values from a specific column. Additionally, I want this list to update automatically when the table is filtered.
I've tried using OFFSET and MATCH functions to create a dynamic range, but it doesn't seem to account for filtering. Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve:
I have a table with columns Category, Product, and Sales.
I want to create a data validation list in another sheet that shows unique Product names based on the Category selected and updates automatically when I filter the table by Category.
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$2, 0, 0, COUNTA(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$100), 1)

However, this doesn't filter out duplicates or consider filtered results. How can I adjust this to meet my requirements?
Any insights or alternative approaches using advanced Excel functions or even VBA would be greatly appreciated!

Instead of using OFFSET() (Volatile functions are not suggestive because they are single threaded, recalculates whenever there is a change in anyopen workbook also slows down the working functionality of excel) use MAP() function with SUBTOTAL() also please post some sample data so that one can help you with a solution ! One more thing if you are asking for VBA solution then you should show users what you have tired on your own to come up !

You could do a spill formula that filters your input and only gives the unique results then use the offset method you have to reference those cells for your data validation  as a named range in the validation

Maybe something like =UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A13,MAP(A2:A13,LAMBDA(MyArray, SUBTOTAL(3,MyArray)<>0)))) where A2:A13 is your original list.
